# Android Emulator cannot be started in visual studio 2017

Tags: c#, xamarin, visual-studio-2017, android-emulator

I am working On Xamrin Project and when I run my application on Android Emulator, it gives me this error each time I try to launch it :

```
getGLES2ExtensionString: Could not find GLES 2.x config!  
Failed to obtain GLES 2.x extensions string!  
Could not initialize emulated framebuffer  
emulator: ERROR: Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, use '-gpu off' to disable it.
```

I have tried to re-create the android device many times but still not working.

Any help please?

Comment: Edit your AVD and uncheck **Use Host GPU**  option.Then save and restart your emulator.

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT SOLVED!  thank you .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem occurs because AVD tries to render graphics using system's graphics card and could not do that either because your system's graphics driver is not up to date or it does not support this so here is the solution.

1.Edit your AVD.

2.Uncheck **Use Host GPU** option.

3.Click Finish (Save).

4.Restart your emulator.